# Using locate, pipe and grep to find files with certain keywords in their names

Tags: linux, bash, grep, pipe, locate

I am not a expert user of any of the two commands but as per my understanding,

if I want to search "Theory of Computation" book on my computer,

`locate -i computation | grep -i theory` should give me all and only files with both `theroy` and `computation` in their names.

`locate -i computation` should output all files with `computation` in their names and from that list, thanks to the pipe, `grep -i theory` should output all the files having `theory` in their names, thus giving me my desired output.

However, when I run the above command, I get outputs like

`/root/books/History theory and practice of the electric telegraph.pdf` which means that my understanding of at least one of these commands (or pipe) is wrong. Where am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see anything wrong with the commands that you are using.  (And they work for me ... though obviously that doesn't explain your situation.)

---

One possible cause for what you are seeing is that the `mlocate.db` file is stale or mangled.  The file is supposed to be updated on a daily basis by `cron`.  However, if you habitually turn off your machine every night, then it might only be run very occasionally.  This *might* cause it to report incorrect hits.  Another possibility is that you have made a large number of changes to the file system since the last rebuild of the database.

I suggest that you do the following:

- check the timestamps on the `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db` file to see if it looks stale
- if warranted, use `updatedb` to rebuild the database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked mlocate.db as you suggest and it seems like it did run last night. ls -l gave: `-rw-r----- 1 root slocate 24310079 2014-12-12 03:41 /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db`. I'm running updatedb again just to be sure. Will update once done.